# Use python to grep lines from one file out of another file

Tags: python, grep

Similar question to alternative of "grep" in python; but the complexity here is what is grepped is variable (lines) from another file. I cannot figure out how to do this using functions like re.findall()

file1:

```
1  20  200
1  30  300
```

file2:

```
1  20  200  0.1  0.5
1  20  200  0.3  0.1
1  30  300  0.2  0.6
1  40  400  0.9  0.6
2  50  300  0.5  0.7
```

Each line from file1 is my pattern; and I need to search such pattern from file2.
Then result should be:

```
    1  20  200  0.1  0.5
    1  20  200  0.3  0.1
    1  30  300  0.2  0.6
```

I've been trying to solve the problem using either bash or python,but cannot figure out.
thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a non-regex based solution:

```
with open('/tmp/file1') as f:
  lines1 = f.readlines()

with open('/tmp/file2') as f:
  for line in f:
    if any(line.startswith(x.strip()) for x in lines1):
      print line,
```

Comment: Take my +1 for use of string methods instead of regex. ;) Improvement: I would make `line1` a set, which speeds up the membership test from `O(n)` to `O(1)`.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but the code never does a membership test on `lines1`, it only iterates over the contents of `lines1`?

Comment: It does the test inside the second loop (in the second-to-last line of the code)

Comment: @Li-aungYip Could you explain your comment, because I'm in agreement with the comment from srgerg here

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact the the `|` character in a regular expression means to match either the pattern on its left, or the pattern on its right:

```
import re

with open('file1') as file1:
    patterns = "|".join(re.escape(line.rstrip()) for line in file1)

regexp = re.compile(patterns)
with open('file2') as file2:
    for line in file2:
        if regexp.search(line):
            print line.rstrip()
```

When I tried this on your sample files, it output:

```
1   20  200 0.1 0.5
1   20  200 0.3 0.1
1   30  300 0.2 0.6
```

Incidentally, if you want to solve this problem in bash, the following should do it:

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need your own loop

```
file1patterns = [ re.Pattern(l) for l in f1.readlines() ]
lineToMatch = 0
matchedLines = []
for line in f2.readlines():
  if file1patterns[lineToMatch].matches(line):
    matchedLines += line
    lineToMatch += 1
  else:
    lineToMatch = 0
    matchedLines = []
  if len(matchedLines) == len(file1patterns)
    print matchedLines
    lineToMatch = 0
    matchedLines = []
```

(Not actual compiling Python, but hopefully enough for you to move forward)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Read in all lines from file 1, split them and add them as tuples to a set. This will help us to do faster lookups in the next step.

```
with open('file1', 'r') as f:
    file1_lines = set([tuple(line.strip().split()) for line in f])
```

Step 2: Filter lines from file2 that meet your criteria i.e if they start with any of the lines in file1:

```
with open('file2', 'r') as f2:
    for line in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: tuple(x.split()[:3]) in file1_lines, f2):
        print line
```